# how to store array values on database in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

```xml
<label class=" ORGAD1-labeltext2">Color</label>
<select class="select-color-multiple  col-sm-12 ORGAD16-color"  multiple="multiple" name="color[]" id="color">
    <option value="">choose color</option>
    <option value="1" >Black</option>
    <option value="2">White</option>
    <option value="3">Green</option>
    <option value="4">Red</option>
    <option value="5">Blue</option>
</select>
```

In dropdown I select multiple values eg:2 (white) 4(red) 5(blue)
passes to controller

```php
$rules['color' => 'required']
$colors = $Request->color;
$choosecolors = implode(',', $colors);

[ dd(colors) if made dd means its shows "1,2,3"]

$store = modelcolor::insertcolors($choose)
```

In my model  model color

```php
public static function  insertcolors($choose)
{
    $createColor = new Colorstable;
    $createColor->colorslist = $choose;
}
```

If store this value means its shows following error:

> SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'colorslist' at row 1

here colorlist column is in `int(11)`

Comment: As you crate a string of values, then the column's type should be a `varchar` instead of an `int`. Int's cannot store commas or spaces, so it very likely that the example is only saving 1 because the data is truncated at the first comma for not being a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do string with your **implode**, so you have to change your column **int** to **varchar**